# htaccess 301 redirect shows as 302 in headers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

Hi I have this redict in my .htaccess file,  it redirects domain.com to wwww.domain.com, the redirections is working fine, but when I check the header it shows as 302 instead of 301, any idea as to why it wouldnt come up as 301? thank you

```
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:domain.com]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please post your entire .htaccess.

Comment: `it redirects domain.com to wwww.domain.com` That is not what these rules are doing.